# NPM package - reference source file

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm-package

I was wondering if it was possible to reference the source file of a Node JS NPM package. (As in the code inside of /node-modules/package-name)
I've thought about going up a directory until the node-modules folder is found, but I'm not sure if that would work with some file structures. Can packages be used with require if the node-modules folder is below the javascript file?

Any help is great, thanks.

Comment: It's hard to understand what you are trying to do and why

Comment: You can do `import MyFile from 'my-package/some-folder/some-file.js'`, or `require('my-package/some-folder/some-file.js')` (depending if you do ESM or not)

Comment: @Lux this doesn’t help read the *source*, i.e. a string (as opposed to exported JS object handles) at runtime.